# Custom query filter

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have entities in my datastore like this:

```
class Location(ndb.Model):
    x = ndb.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    y = ndb.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    (other properties here)
```

Now I need to filter the entities in my datastore based on their distance from a user defined location. Can I somehow pass a function that checks if the location is correct as a filter, or is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly using the datastore, definitely not.

You would need to grab everything and do the computations via your code.

for instance if your userLocation is (5,4), and you have a max distance of 10, you would need to grab everything with x>-5 and x<15 and y>-6 and y< 14 and manually take off those who are too far.